# Is there a way to increment Firestore FieldValue by 0 if the value is NaN or undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am building a Next JS app with Firebase as the backend and I am using Firebase cloud functions to update certain Firestore fields. I use an onCreate trigger that carries the numbers by which I increment with.

The data looks something like this:

```
{
  "docId": "a4wwdslidinwle",
  "metaData": [
    {
      "data": "age",
      "count": 1
    }, 
    {
      "data": "skill",
      "count": 3
    }
  ],
  "phoneNumber": "0800182712",
  "uid": "j10wmCUhUWPxYJpIElBxmFAEI6l1"
}
```

and I increment the fields like this:

```
// INCREMENT FIRESTORE FIELD VALUE
var userData = admin.firestore().collection("user")
.doc(data.uid).update({
    age: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(dataObject.age),
    skill: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(dataObject.skill),
    starRating: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(dataObject.starRating)
})
```

My challenge is, when the document is created and it doesn't have the `starRating` item, the cloud function throws an error that says the `FieldValue.increment()` did not have a valid number. It works fine when the star Rating is set to a value.

Is there a way to increment by 0 if that value is missing from the document?

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Read the document, check to see what the values are, set them to what they should be, then write the document back. You won't be able to use a simple increment operation as you are now.  If you don't want to do this, then make sure those fields have starting number values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `increment` operator can safely be called with a value of `0`, so:

```
starRating: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(
  dataObject.starRating ? dataObject.starRating : 0
)
```

Comment: Please note that calling increment(0) will NOT actually increment by 0, it will set it to 0. This is not documented and very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand your question, you can simply check for the existence of the field as follows:

```
const updateObject = {
    age: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(dataObject.age),
    skill: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(dataObject.skill),
}
if (dataObject.starRating) {
   updateObject.starRating =  admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(dataObject.starRating)
} else {
   updateObject.starRating = 0;
}
admin.firestore().collection("user").doc(data.uid).update(updateObject);
```